# Change axis style python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm making a simple plot of an exponentially decaying cos curve in python. The code is below, there's no problem with the code actually running, I was just wondering if there's a way to change the way python displays the graph so rather than being enclosed by the axes like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBtt4.png) it has the axes like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZEPz.png). It's not an urgent problem, it's just to make the plot match more closely with other parts of my report.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
t = np.linspace(0, 4, 10000)
r=1
x = t
y = r * np.exp(-t)*np.cos(10*t)

plt.plot(x,y,'-')
plt.plot(x,np.zeros(10000),'k-')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Axis line style demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_axisline_style.html) from the matplotlib gallery.

Specifically, the lines:

```
ax = SubplotZero(fig, 111)

...

for direction in ["left", "right", "bottom", "top"]: 
    ax.axis[direction].set_visible(False)
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find it on the matplotlib site for some reason, guess I didn't look hard enough!