# Insert linesyle in axis label

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am doing some plots with matplotlib. Specifically I am plotting two functions in the same canvas using two y axis (one on the usual left and the other on the right, they have different scales). In order to make more clear what curve belongs to what axis I would to like to add a line style symbol on the y label similarly to what it's automatically generated with the legend. Is it something possible to do with matplotlib or I have to give up?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably not what you are looking for but definitely possible: plot an hline from your curve to an axis (by taking a random point from your curve, then putting the coordinates to `plt.hlines(x_min=x_min, x_max=some_x_coordinate, y=respective_y_coordinate)` when your point has coordinates (some_x_coordinate, respective_y_coordinate)

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481413/change-axis-style-python

Comment: Hi Jetman, thanks for the reply but it is not exactly what I was looking for!